# Мультизагрузочная флэшка

Tags: администрирование

Вопрос избитый, но все же остаются вопросы.

В наличии:

```
1. загрузочная флешка
2. образы Windows 8.1, Windows 7, Debian 8.1
3. На флешке установлен grub4dos (для загрузки в Legacy-режиме)
4. Установлен GRUB2 (для загрузки в EFI режиме)
```

Grub4dos я настраивать умею, а вот с GRUB2 работать не приходилось. Подскажите как прописать установку Debian, Windows8 и Windows7 (интересует именно EFI загрузка)

Answer (score 2):

Multiboot Flash Filth Edition - готовая сборка. Можно дополнить своими ISO, ПО и утилитами. Конфигурация - текстовый файл. Успешно загружаются и устанавливаются Windows XP, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Debian, Ubuntu, ESXi. Предустановлены различные LiveCD, средства тестирования ОЗУ и HDD. Работает как с EFI так и с Legacy загрузкой.
Есть средство тестирования (MobaLiveCD) без загрузки "железа" с флешки/usb-hdd.  Пользуюсь не первый год.

Comment: Ответы-ссылки тут не приветствуются. Завтра торент закроют - и ваш ответ станет бесполезным. Приведите название рекомендуемой вами программы и инструкцию.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за комментарий, я новичок в этом сообществе.  ответ изменил.